# Basic subsistence balance for a visit to France

Tags: visas, france, schengen-visas

I am 21 years old and just started working 6 months ago and have plans to go to France for 7 days. I need to know what is the minimum subsistence balance. And I also would like advice if I don't make the basic subsistence figure can I get a guarantee?

Comment: The minimum funds depend on various parameters. "Seven days" is a short period (so no need for extra clothes, laundry, consumable personal items, etc. But it depends on the kind of travel you intend to to (and that you proof). Backpack? Alone or with friends? Advance booking (and paid): hotels/hostels/camping, trains, etc. ?  This is part of your job (by checking online and on the guides): could you afford the travel? How much you can find for accommodation and food.

Answer (score 2):

- To get a visa, you will have to show that you are a *credible* tourist. The balance is not the key issue, you will have to show income and expenditures that allow you to spend money on travel. If the travel is not paid by yourself, then you will *also* have to explain who pays, why, and where the money comes from.
- To be allowed into France, you will have to show that you can cover your cost of living. Quick googling got me €120/day (which seems high).

Comment: 120Eur seems high to me too. People I know recently got visas for a weekend in Paris on the basis of 60 EUR per day.